# Acentuação de nomes indígenas no banco de dados Oracle

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, codificação-de-caracteres, acentuação, unicode

Estamos com uma situação de inclusão de registros de nomes indígenas no banco Oracle, onde há uma variação de acentuação, podendo ter "e" ou "u" com til.
Nossos parâmetros do Oracle (versão 9i) são 
NLS_LANGUAGE = BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE
NLS_TERRITORY = BRAZIL

Comment: Qual a pergunta ou a duvida? não entendi

Comment: Como colocar e com til ou u com til no database.

Answer (score 2):

Há dois elementos distintos envolvidos:

- Os charsets utilizados na criação da sua base de dados.
- O charset utilizado para apresentação dos dados.

Na criação da base de dados são definidos `NLS_CHARACTERSET` e `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET`. Estes parâmetros podem ser verificados pela query:

```
select * 
from nls_database_parameters 
where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET' 
or parameter='NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET';
```

Em relação ao charset utilizado para apresentação dos dados, sugiro configurar `NLS_LANG`, o qual possui o formato `<LANGUAGE>_<TERRITORY>.<CHARACTER_SET>`. No caso teríamos `<LANGUAGE> = BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE`, `<TERRITORY> = BRAZIL` e `<CHARACTER SET>` que pode ser:

```
AL16UTF16
AL32UTF8
UTF8
US7ASCII      [X]
WE8ISO8859P1  [X]
WE8ISO8859P15 [X]
WE8MSWIN1252  [X]
```

Os charsets marcados com `[X]` não permitem as letras *e* ou *u* com *til*. Veja por exemplo o `WE8ISO8859P1 (ISO 8859-1)`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Portanto, você terá de usar Unicode, como por exemplo:

```
NLS_LANG = BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE_BRAZIL.UTF8
```